# Python multiprocessing with macOs

Tags: python, macos, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

**I have a mac (MacOs 10.15.4, Python ver 3.82) and need to work in multiprocessing, but on my pc the procedures doesn’t work.**

For example, I have copied a simple parallel python program

```
import multiprocessing as mp  
import time  

def test_function(i):   
    print("function starts" + str(i))  
    time.sleep(1)  
    print("function ends" + str(i))  

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())  
    pool.map(test_function, [i for i in range(4)])  
    pool.close()  
    pool.join()
```

What I expect to see in the output:

```
function starts0  
function ends0  
function starts1  
function ends1  
function starts2  
function ends2  
function starts3  
function ends3
```

Or similar...

What I actually see:

```
= RESTART: /Users/Simulazioni/prova.py    
>>>
```

Just nothing, no errors and no informations, just nothing. I have already try mamy procedure without results. The main problem, I could see, is the call of the function, in fact the instruction:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

doesn’t call the function,

```
def test_function(i):
```

I tried many example of that kind without results.

Is ti possible and/or what's is the easiest way to parallelize in macOs?

Comment: How are you calling your script? I've run your exact code in the same OS/interpreter and get the correct result.

Comment: I am not sure to have undestand the question, but I am just use the interpreter, python shell. 3.8.2. But I have tried many different procedures, and I am sure the multiprocessor with my mac mini (i7) doesn't work.

Comment: Or better, the processor work in multiprocessor way. In other words all cores work, but I have not results of this job. I can't see anything. Just wait and see the processor work.

Comment: How you're executing the program? I'm getting desired output in my macbook

Comment: After your consideration I had a doubt. So I tryed with a different editor (BBS) and the multiprocess works. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is a bit of an old question, but I just faced the same issue and I solved it by using a different multithreading package's version, which is:

```
import multiprocess
```

instead of:

```
import multiprocessing
```

Reference:

https://pypi.org/project/multiprocess/